# How to parse distance data with iphone from google directions api?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, driving-directions, directions

I'm trying to get the distance between two places (by way of roads), and I get that an http request will return a XML with the following data

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#XML

but I don't get how to use NSXMLParser to get the total distance.  I would assume to use the

```
parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes
```

method but not sure how this works.  The element I would want I guess is "directions" but there's a couple elements like that.  How do I specify which one I want?  Does it have to do with the "attributes" parameter?

Comment: are we not supposed to put thanks at the end?  getting kinda picky...

Comment: Yeah, we're not allowed to start with "Hello" either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSXMLParser` is a SAX parser, and that means you must provide callback methods for various parse events while the document is processed. The Google documentation you link to makes me think these documents are not terribly large, and so I would personally not use a SAX parser.

A DOM parser, such as `NSXMLDocument` is much easier to use, but unfortunately Apple did not include `NSXMLDocument` in the iOS SDK. There are several alternatives, including [TouchXML](http://github.com/schwa/TouchXML).

If you only care about the total distance, and not the distance of each leg or step, then a simple XPath query will get all of the distances for you: `//leg/step/distance/value`. Loop through them and sum them up.

Comment: As a corollary: consider using the JSON API, as JSON is faster to parse than XML.

Answer (score 0):

You use didStartElement to find element you need, than you should use foundCharacters method to gather content of tag (it can be called more than ones), so only when didEndElement method is called you can use content of tag for whatever you want.

Comment: yeah i get that, but as I said, there are several elements that have the same tags, but in different layers of the file.  I think I'm going to try using the columnNumber method maybe?

Comment: As fare as I understand, you want to pass through xml file and collect information from all <distance> tags?